# TableModel removeRow() definition

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jtable

This is my tableModel:

```
public class d9tableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

ArrayList<String> cols = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> data = new ArrayList<>();

public d9tableModel() {
// initial cols and data with database
}

@Override
public int getRowCount() {
    return data.size();
}

@Override
public int getColumnCount() {
    return cols.size();
}

@Override
public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    ArrayList<String> selectedRow = data.get(rowIndex);
    return selectedRow.get(columnIndex);
}

@Override
public String getColumnName(int column) {
    return cols.get(column);
}

public void removeRow(int rowNumber) {
    data.remove(rowNumber);
}
}
```

Now, after passing a `convertRowIndexToModel` line number, Don't remove row!

Comment: -1 for still not having learned anything (after a bunch of questions and nudgings) a) not applying java naming conventions b) the model doesn't notify its listeners. Actually, I'm near to loosing my patience: Go.Read.And.Understand.A.BasicTutorial.

Comment: why do you have a List<List<String>> .. it's not better create your own class?.. you have to notify to the view `fireTableRowsDeleted(int firstRow, int lastRow)`

Comment: @nachokk by adding `fireTableRowsDeleted(int firstRow, int lastRow)`, Row just remove from table, and after re-run it back!

Comment: @Sajjad why should I vote to re-open? Your edit doesn't show any progress. May (certainly does :-) sound harsh, but you **have** to learn the basics, without you won't be able to understand the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
 public void removeRow(int rowNumber) {
        data.remove(rowNumber);
    }
```

to

```
public void removeRow(int rowNumber) {
    data.remove(rowNumber);
    fireTableRowsDeleted(rowNumber, rowNumber);
}
```

Comment: by adding `fireTableRowsDeleted(int firstRow, int lastRow)`, Row just remove from table, and after re-run it back!

Comment: you have to delete from your db also..execute your query

Comment: @Sajjad <teeth-gritting/> what's so difficult in understanding that the swing _tableModel_ is different from your database _table_? It's **your** job to synchronize both, no magic involved .. Anyway, as long as you don't show a SSCCE your base question is not answerable

Comment: @Sajjad as kleopatra said no magic involved, your db lives in another world, what you can do is register your own listener to the model, and when `fireTableRowsDeleted` gets fired you catch the event and delete from your db, but in some part you have to do " delete from table where ..." OR just before `data.remvoe(rowNumber)`  call a method that make `delete from table where ...`